# How i can add value as number

Tags: javascript

i have problem because it code don't calculate value.

I wrote 11 and is Expenditure: 11, next i wrote 11 and is 1111, but i need 22 so i used minusValue.value **+=** a;

Do you know where is error?

```js
var minusCashField = document.getElementById('minusCashField');
minusCash.addEventListener("click", function() {

var a = minusCashField.value;
minusValue.value += a;
});
```

```html
<div class="threeBox">
            <div class="resultbutton">
                <input class="minusValue" disabled id="minusValue" value=''>
            </div>

</div>
</header>

    
<div class="addFunction">
   
    <fieldset>
<label><strong>Expenditure:</strong></br></label>
    <input placeholder="Enter Expenditure...." tabindex="2" required type="text"  id="minusCashField">
    <button type="submit" id="minusCash">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.value` is returning a string, not a number.

You could convert the string to a number by using a [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```
var number = +input.value;
//           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

your concatinating 2 strings you need to convert them to integers.

```
var minusCashField = document.getElementById('minusCashField');
minusCash.addEventListener("click", function() {

var a = parseInt(minusCashField.value || 0, 10);
minusValue.value = parseInt(minusValue.value || 0, 10) + a;
});
```

Comment: Now i see NAN in field

Comment: check if theres a value first, i just added an or check

Comment: Can you tell me what mean  || 0, 10) this code? i dont understand that?

Comment: you should add other checks making sure the inputs are all numbers then convert it to a integer

Comment: minusCashField.value will return an empty string "" which is falsy in javascript, so adding the `||` will make an expression saying if the value on the left is falsy then return the value to the right.

Comment: var plusCashField = document.getElementById('plusCashField');
addCash.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var inputPlusCash = parseInt(plusCashField.value || 0, 10);
   plusCashBank.value = parseInt(plusCashField.value || 0, 10) + inputPlusCash;
}); I use new code and it value is multiplied

Comment: read your code carefully. Without a struggle, there can be no progress.

Comment: I see i must use :   plusCashBank.value = parseInt(plusValue.value || 0, 10) + inputPlusCash;. Tell my why i use here plusValue it is variable or id? becouse i dont have variable name plusValue . I had only: var plusCashBank = document.getElementById('plusValue');

Answer (score 0):

Because the values of those inputs will be strings, you need to convert the strings to numbers before any math operations can be performed - both the string value you assign to `a`, and the value contained in the results to which you add `a`.

```
minusCash.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var a = Number(minusCashField.value);
  minusValue.value = Number(minusValue.value) + a;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use parseInt() to convert the string to integer.

```js
var minusCashField = document.getElementById('minusCashField');
minusCash.addEventListener("click", function() {

    var a = parseInt(minusCashField.value || 0, 10);
    minusValue.value = parseInt(minusValue.value || 0, 10) + a;
});
```

```html
<div class="threeBox">
    <div class="resultbutton">
        <input class="minusValue" disabled id="minusValue" value=''>
    </div>

</div>
</header>


<div class="addFunction">

    <fieldset>
        <label><strong>Expenditure:</strong></br></label>
        <input placeholder="Enter Expenditure...." tabindex="2" required type="text" id="minusCashField">
        <button type="submit" id="minusCash">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>

</div>
```